Getting Macro error "PasteSpecial of object '_Worksheet' failed" while pasting from clipboard
I am trying to paste Clipboard data which has text and images combined into a worksheet and getting

"Run-time error '1004': Method PasteSpecial of object
'_Worksheet'failed"

Here is my code:
Sub Paste()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim LastRow As Long

' Set the worksheet you want to work on
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
ws.Range("B2").Select
ws.PasteSpecial Format:="HTML", Link:=False, 
DisplayAsIcon:=False, NoHTMLFormatting:=True

End Sub


You must use a MSForms.DataObject to interact with the clipboard:
Sub ObjectFromClipboard()

  Dim oData As Object

  Set oData = CreateObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")

  oData.GetFromClipboard

  Range("A1").PasteSpecial 'Adjust as required
  
End Sub

This post ads more background info and error handling routines, this one is also useful.

Whenever I had to build rough code for copying and pasting (probably even using SendKeys with Ctrl+C) I used the ActiveSheet. to avoid an error like you describe. Using .Sheet().Range() as usual doesn't seem to be sufficient in some cases - so the code basically looks like this:
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Select

ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="HTML"

I know .Select shall be avoided, but however for me it turned out to run extremely robust just like this.
But using .GetFromClipboard is way more elegant and faster and (in case you emptied the clipboard right before) also can be used in a loop to check if copying was already completed and to wait as long as necessary. You should really check it out.
